# C++ OpenMP for loop race condition

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I am solving a problem where I have `N` items and `M` constraints related to this items. Each item has a value and `M` parameters. I'm using `GetBound` function to calculate the upper bound (the maximum value in a set of items satisfying each constraint) at the current state of the algorithm. I use a for loop to calculate `M` different bounds (for each constraint) and then my function returns the lowest bound I have found. I want to use OpenMP to make the `for` loop work in parallel to save some time, but for some reason it doesn't work (the running time of the algorithm practically does not change). I think it is due to the fact that inside the loop I work with vectors, but i don't understand why a race condition happens, because during each loop iteration I'm writing only the vector elements controlled by a single thread. I am not even changing vector values (EDITOR's REMARK: OP changes the value of `bounds` defined outside the loop), I'm just finding the values I need to calculate the bound.

```
pair<double, int> GetBound(
MultidimensionalKnapsack knapsack, vector<vector<int>> indices, set<Item> I, set<Item> E) {
int n = knapsack.getN();
int m = knapsack.getM();
vector<Item> items = knapsack.getItems();
vector<int> b = knapsack.getB();
vector<pair<double, int>> bounds(m);
     #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2)
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    int index = -1;
    double weight = 0;
    vector<double> seq(n);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if (I.count(items[j]) == 1) {
            weight += items[j].getConstraights()[i];
            seq[j] = 1;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if ((I.count(items[indices[i][j]]) == 0) && (E.count(items[indices[i][j]]) == 0)) {
            if (weight + items[indices[i][j]].getConstraights()[i] <= b[i]) {
                weight += items[indices[i][j]].getConstraights()[i];
                seq[indices[i][j]] = 1;
            }
            else {
                seq[indices[i][j]] = (b[i] - weight) / items[indices[i][j]].getConstraights()[i];
                weight = b[i];
                index = indices[i][j];
            }
        }
    }
    int boundSum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        boundSum += seq[j] * items[j].getValue();
    }
    bounds[i].first = boundSum;
    bounds[i].second = index;
}

double min = bounds[0].first;
int minIndex = -1;
for (auto bound : bounds)
{
    if (bound.first < min) {
        min = bound.first;
        minIndex = bound.second;
    }
}
return make_pair(min, minIndex);
}
```

I'm writing the values in a global vector variable at the end of the loop, but it seems that the problem is hidden in another nested loop (the biggest one).

Comment: What are the execution times of the function with and without OpenMP? How many cores do you have? Can you also provide numbers for higher numbers of threads?

Comment: The problem with object programming when it comes to mutithreading is that one cannot easily ensure the classes are thread-safe. Even with `const`, object can silently mutate in C++ and AFAIK there is no way to ensure they are immutable. Thus, you need to carefully check the classes if you wrote them, or the documentation of the library if they are coming from a third-party software. Alternatively you can provide the class implementation if they are not too big or better: make a minimal reproducible example. To check this hypothesis, you could copy the values arrays before the loop.

Comment: What makes you think you have a race condition?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)